# Xcode - How to get canvas view back

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I recently removed the canvas preview window (by holding the left mouse button down and pushing it to the right) from two of my SwiftUI files in Xcode and I don't know how to get it back. I also checked "Canvas" but it still does not appear in those files. [image]

Do you have any ideas how to get it back?
I'm using the latest Xcode and macOS.

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most likely, you also removed the `PreviewProvider` struct. To enable the canvas, you need this (otherwise Xcode doesn't know what to preview).

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hi")
    }
}
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought it wasn't commented out. But I checked again and it was. Thank you.